# Typecheck SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, typechecking

Is there any relational database that can output the return type of a query before running it? As an example, a query like this `GIVE_TYPES SELECT name, age FROM person` would give a result like `VARCHAR(255), INTEGER` without actually executing the query. If this is not a possibility, why is that the case?

EDIT
The first comment made me realize that I need to give a slightly more complicated use case. Imagine if the query were something like this:

```
SELECT parent_name, COUNT(name) FROM person GROUP BY parent_name;
```

To select the names of all parents and the number of children they have. I would expect something like `VARCHAR(255), INTEGER` as the result for this as well, but a column inspection would not let me know about `COUNT`'s return type.

Comment: You can call "SHOW COLUMNS FROM person" to show all the types of the columns in the person table. You can do this for any table; I'm not sure if this is possible for just a query.

Comment: On SQL Server, you can query the information schema views to get the datatypes of the columns in a table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And which programming language are you using?

Comment: I have updated the question to specify the vendor. I commonly use Haskell and am interested in the answer as it pertains to my Haskell workflow (with `persistent` and `esqueleto`), but this question does not concern programming languages.

Comment: It does concern the programming language, because usually the driver API of the language offers a way to describe the structure of a result, e.g. `ResultSet.getResultSetMetaData()` in Java/JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

Count's return type always is int.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx

Comment: and if you add a columns of all null values (to put values in later in a complex process )that is always int too unless you specifically cast it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on top of persistent and esqueleto, then I don't think you're going to have simple access to this sort of information. In particular, I assume any unrecognized PostgreSQL types just get mapped to a Haskell String or Text.

About the best you can do is:

1. CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 AS  LIMIT 0
2. SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='t1' AND schema_name=...
3. DROP TABLE t1;

You'll want to identify the temporary schema-name for your table t1 (in the format pg_temp_xxx).

This (plus perhaps some follow-up queries on the information-schema for type details) should give you details on all columns of your result-set.